# Como humanizar datas em javascript

Tags: javascript, html, data

Dada uma data ex: 24/05/1982, como transformar em anos, meses e dias?
No exemplo acima seria convertida em 33 anos 1 mês e 1 dia.
A idéia é fazer tudo em Javascript.

Comment: Você quer saber a diferença entre a data atual e a data dada?

Comment: não, apenas converter mesmo. Dada uma data, quero convertê-la

Comment: Aqui ele tá obtendo outra coisa como resposta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aconselho a você usar o plugin [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/):
Aí fica fácil, é só usar a função [duration()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) pra calcular a duração do tempo atual com a data desejada:

```js
var hoje = moment();
var dia  = moment("24-05-1982", "DD-MM-YYYY");
var duracao = moment.duration(hoje.valueOf()-dia.valueOf(), 'milliseconds');

document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = duracao.years() + " anos, " + duracao.months() + " meses e " + duracao.days() + " dias.";
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<p id="dias"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Usar o moment.js é uma boa, mas calcular a diferença em milissegundos para depois formatar o resultado em anos, meses e dias não é.

Quando você pede para o moment formatar uma quantidade de milissegundos para meses/anos, ele assume que cada mês tem 30 dias, retornando um resultado que dificilmente será o esperado.

Nessa issue do moment.js um dos autores desencoraja o uso de milissegundos para calcular diferença entre datas:
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1466

A melhor maneira é calcular as unidades anos, meses e dias separadamente:

```js
var inicio = moment('24-05-1982', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
var agora = moment('2015-06-25');

var diferenca = moment.duration({
    years: agora.year() - inicio.year(),
    months: agora.month() - inicio.month(),
    days: agora.date() - inicio.date()
});

document.getElementById("anos").innerHTML = diferenca.years() + ' ano(s)';
document.getElementById("meses").innerHTML = diferenca.months() + ' mese(s)';
document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = diferenca.days() + ' dia(s)';
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<p>Se passaram <b id="anos"></b>, <b id="meses"></b> e <b id="dias"></b>.</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Não é tão simples como parece ser. Tenho exemplo em php.... Quem sabe você não consegue transpor a idéia para o javascript....

```
function dateDiff($dia1) {
// This is a simple script to calculate the difference between two dates
// and express it in years, months and days
// 
// use as in: "my daughter is 4 years, 2 month and 17 days old" ... :-)
//
// Feel free to use this script for whatever you want
// 
// version 0.1 / 2002-10-3
//
// please send comments and feedback to webmaster@lotekk.net
//

// ****************************************************************************

// configure the base date here
$d1 = explode('/', $dia1);
$base_day       = $d1[0];       // no leading "0"
$base_mon       = $d1[1];       // no leading "0"
$base_yr        = $d1[2];       // use 4 digit years!

// get the current date (today) -- change this if you need a fixed date
$current_day        = date ("j");
$current_mon        = date ("n");
$current_yr     = date ("Y");

// and now .... calculate the difference! :-)

// overflow is always caused by max days of $base_mon
// so we need to know how many days $base_mon had
$base_mon_max       = date ("t",mktime (0,0,0,$base_mon,$base_day,$base_yr));

// days left till the end of that month
$base_day_diff      = $base_mon_max - $base_day;

// month left till end of that year
// substract one to handle overflow correctly
$base_mon_diff      = 12 - $base_mon - 1;

// start on jan 1st of the next year
$start_day      = 1;
$start_mon      = 1;
$start_yr       = $base_yr + 1;

// difference to that 1st of jan
$day_diff   = ($current_day - $start_day) + 1;  // add today
$mon_diff   = ($current_mon - $start_mon) + 1;  // add current month
$yr_diff    = ($current_yr - $start_yr);

// and add the rest of $base_yr
$day_diff   = $day_diff + $base_day_diff;
$mon_diff   = $mon_diff + $base_mon_diff;

// handle overflow of days
if ($day_diff >= $base_mon_max)
{
    $day_diff = $day_diff - $base_mon_max;
    $mon_diff = $mon_diff + 1;
}

// handle overflow of years
if ($mon_diff >= 12)
{
    $mon_diff = $mon_diff - 12;
    $yr_diff = $yr_diff + 1;
}

// the results are here:

// $yr_diff     --> the years between the two dates
// $mon_diff    --> the month between the two dates
// $day_diff    --> the days between the two dates

// ****************************************************************************

// this is just to make it look nicer
$years = "anos";
$days = "dias";
$meses = "meses";
if ($yr_diff == "1") $years = "ano";
if ($day_diff == "1") $days = "dia";
if ($mon_diff=="1") $meses = "mês";

    // here we go
    $m = $d = "";
    if ($mon_diff > 0) {
        if ($day_diff > 0) {
            $m = ", $mon_diff $meses";      
        } else {
            $m = " e $mon_diff $meses";
        }
    }

    if ($day_diff > 0) {
        $d = " e $day_diff $days";
    }

    //return "$yr_diff $years, $mon_diff $meses e $day_diff $days";
    return "$yr_diff $years$m$d";
}
```